# Delete Method based on condition in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created an application in MVC 4 using Razor HTML. I have set up a model that has a few properties and my delete method which is posted below. This method works perfectly except for the fact that I don't want it to allow me to delete anything if one of the properties is not a certain number. How can i implement that in this method?

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
{
Material material = db.Materials.Find(id);
if(material == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(material);
}


[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
Material material = db.Materials.Find(id);
db.Materials.Remove(material);
db.SaveChanges();
return RedirecttoAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: "if one of the properties is not a certain number". Wouldn't a simple `if` statement work?

Comment: As far as I understand you just need a simple `if` clause. So I guess, you mean something else. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both your get and post actions, check the property and return an alternate "no delete allowed" view if the property you are checking doesn't have an allowable value.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
{

    Material material = db.Materials.Find(id);
    if(material == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    else if (material.CheckedProperty != AllowableValue)
    {
        return View("DeleteNotAllowed", material);
    }
    return View(material);
}


[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Material material = db.Materials.Find(id);
    if (material.CheckedProperty != AllowableValue)
    {
         return View("DeleteNotAllowed", material);
    }

    db.Materials.Remove(material);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirecttoAction("Index");
}
```